# How to find total discount - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to output the total exclusive discount. For example, if there are two products and each product cost is 1000 and 10% discount on both of them. Then the total exclusive would be 200. But my code is displaying a discount of only 1 product

Here is jQuery Code

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#invoice_item_price, #invoice_item_quantity, #invoice_item_discount', function() {

  var sum = 0;
  
  $('.invoice-table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
    var price = $(this).find('#invoice_item_price').val();
    var quantity = $(this).find('#invoice_item_quantity').val();
    var discount = $(this).find('#invoice_item_discount').val();
    var tax = $(this).find('#invoice_item_tax').val();
    var total = (quantity * price);

    if (discount) {
      var dec = (discount / 100).toFixed(2);
      var mult = total * dec;
      $("#invoice_total_discount").text(mult);
      total = total - mult;
    }

    $(this).find('#invoice_item_total_amount').val(total);
    sum += total;
  });

  $('#invoice_subtotal').text(sum);
  $('#invoice_total_amount').text(sum);

});
```

$("#invoice_total_discount").text(mult); This would output the discount in span tag but it is displaying the discount of only 1 product. I'm trying to show the total exclusive discount of all products

Comment: **Id must be unique** .. use classes instead

Comment: okay, I will! but this wouldn't solve the problem

Comment: @shaktigoyal but it's a **huge** step forward!

Comment: Why do you use the `"keyup"` event? What if I use my mouse any copy paste a value into? Please, use always the `"input"` event. (keyup has its couple of use cases - yours in not one of those).

Comment: Also, input elements will always store their values as strings - even if the value is a number. So this line (and others like it) `var price = $(this).find('#invoice_item_price').val();` will give you "10.50", not 10.50. When doing math in javascript, always make sure you're working with numbers. As in `var total = (Number(quantity) * Number(price));` or, in shorthand, `var total = (+quantity * +price);` - The `+`will automatically convert that variable to a number

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistakes.

Comment: If someone knows the solution to the actual problem that I'm facing, then please answer it. I will appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments: IDs have to be unique therefor you should change them to classes. To get the total discount you simply have to add another variable to your script (for example `disc`) like `sum` that counts the calculated discount for every row.

Since `tax` isn't used in this example i removed it. And because `invoice_subtotal` shows the same like `invoice_total_amount` i replaced it with an `invoice_total_discount` for the total discount.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.invoice_item_price, .invoice_item_quantity, .invoice_item_discount', function() {

  var sum = 0;
  var disc = 0;
  
  $('.invoice-table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
    var price = $(this).find('.invoice_item_price').val();
    var quantity = $(this).find('.invoice_item_quantity').val();
    var discount = $(this).find('.invoice_item_discount').val();
    var total = quantity * price;

    if (discount) {
      var dec = (discount / 100).toFixed(2);
      var mult = total * dec;
      disc += mult;
      total = total - mult;
    }

    $(this).find('.invoice_item_total_amount').val(total);
    sum += total;
  });

  $('#invoice_total_amount').text(sum);
  $("#invoice_total_discount").text(disc);

});
```

```css
input {
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="invoice-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Discount</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="invoice_item_price"></td>
      <td><input class="invoice_item_quantity"></td>
      <td><input class="invoice_item_discount"></td>
      <td><input class="invoice_item_total_amount" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="invoice_item_price"></td>
      <td><input class="invoice_item_quantity"></td>
      <td><input class="invoice_item_discount"></td>
      <td><input class="invoice_item_total_amount" readonly></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div>Total amount: <span id="invoice_total_amount"></span></div>
<div>Total discount: <span id="invoice_total_discount"></span></div>
```